# Should I be using the Office API rather than VBA macros for automating word formatting?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

I've been creating VBAs macros to automate manual formatting we do on Word documents. Given VBA is on it's way out I've just started looking at the Office 365 API.  But it feels a bit like overkill when I just want to apply formatting to specific rows in a document or delete empty rows from a table in Microsoft Word. Thoughts? Are people still creating VBA macros?

Comment: I am creating VBA macros. Not only that, I have decided that APIs are on their way out. They are too sensitive for programming by lay people (basically the VBA crowd) and not as convenient as their equivalents in .NET. I don't use Office 365. Perhaps MS has improved the way APIs work there. But even if so, I doubt that VBA will be on its way out anytime soon. As you say yourself, it offers a very convenient way to do simple tasks.

Comment: Thanks - endless googling isn't really leading me to a answer on this so need a cross-check.